# How to open any PDF and word file in Swing JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, pdf, ms-word, jtextarea

I'm doing Java swing application to open any PDF, word, notepad or Java file. 
But I'm only able to open text file.

PDF and word is opening but not properly so please help me.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where is the problem? How do you parse pdf and word files? How do you display them in swing?

Comment: i know about jpeadl(java pdf library ) but i dnt knw know that can i use it with my swing application to only open and read pdf files...thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JTextArea` does not support rich (styled) text.  While `JTextPane` and `JEditorPane` support simple styled text (e.g. HTML & RTF).  They do not support more complex formats like Word documents or PDF.

This will require a custom component that supports those document types.  There is no component provided with the JSE (core Java) that can render them.

Comment: i don't have used any tool or java PDF library...i m simply opening it in jtextarea using jfilechooser of swing

Comment: thanks .... please tell me any java PDF library to use in swing application.

Comment: I have never tried using Word or PDF documents.  I suspect two  *separate* searches will be best as I doubt any custom component will support both document types.  In your GUI, you might simply swap between the two custom components using a `CardLayout`.